# Is it possible to manually edit/view KDE's Nepomuk database?

Tags: database, kde, nepomuk

I'd like to know if there's a way to edit the content of the Nepomuk database, ideally with some simple tool.

Some times ago I have recently the indexing of the email, in order to save system resources and to get rid of this kind of results whenever I perform a search from Krunner, and mostly, because I really don't need this feature.

Anyway, if I look in `System settings > Desktop Search > Basic Settings > Nepomuk Semantic Desktop > Details`, I can see that the database still contains, more or less 10K entries for emails. I'd like to get rid of them, is it possible to do so?

Is there some tool to delete/edit the content of the database?

Answer (score -3):

To permanently delete the databases you can delete this folder: `~/.kde4/share/apps/nepomuk/`

After that you can reïndex the data you do want.

Comment: OP wants to view or edit the database, not delete it.